# GitHub Actions Changelog Generator Results in Error

Tags: github-actions, cicd, changelog

I tried using this Changelog Generator in my stages and it results in an error as depicted:

```
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2

  - name: capture changelog
    id: changelog
    uses: metcalfc/changelog-generator@v4.0.1
    with:
      myToken: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

The error that I get:

```
2022-11-01T09:53:03.6356312Z ##[group]Run metcalfc/changelog-generator@v4.0.1
2022-11-01T09:53:03.6356660Z with:
2022-11-01T09:53:03.6357261Z   myToken: ***
2022-11-01T09:53:03.6357690Z   reverse: false
2022-11-01T09:53:03.6357927Z env:
2022-11-01T09:53:03.6358346Z   GITHUB_TOKEN: ***
2022-11-01T09:53:03.6358655Z ##[endgroup]
2022-11-01T09:53:04.4276769Z ##[error]Not Found
```

Is there anything that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the [repository](https://github.com/metcalfc/changelog-generator#error-not-found) and there you can find a nice description why this error occurred:

[image: no found errir]